# Jquery appendTo doesn't do it on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

I cloned an element from a carousel and at the same time I appended it to another `div`. It works all right until I resize the window and stop appending for 2 pixels (1024 - 1025px).

It happens when the carousel changes from 3 items to 4, but this shouldn't affect the `.appendTo` doesn't it?

This is my code

HTML:

```
<!-- Item to append -->
<div id="carousel-clone">
   <div class="item1 news_item " style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 240px;"></div>
</div>


<!-- Appended to -->
<div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 1020px;"></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
//Carousel - fix first item on scroll
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
    var $cloned = $('.bx-viewport .carousel .news_item.item1').clone();
    $('#carousel-clone').html($cloned);
    $("#carousel-clone").appendTo(".bx-wrapper");
});
```

Comment: Depends on what the 'carousel' is doing with the div/wrapper/etc.  If it's handling events and *not* using event delegation, then it won't pick up the new clone.

Comment: It's cloning it all right, the problem is that for those 2 seconds, it doesn't append it, which is weird...

Comment: I would put a timeout on that so it only fires at resize end otherwise you can end up doing that hundreds of times in a single resize action